# finding neighbours in a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem where I have a numpy ndarray. Now, this array can be 2D or 3D depending on the available input and what I would like to do is get the "previous" neighbours of each of the samples along each of the axes. So in 2D, if one imagines the following array:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
4 3 2 1
```

Now I only need the indexes for values that actually have a valid "previous" neighbour (so not including the top and left border entries). So this should return me (something like):

```
[[0, 1], [1, 0]], [[1, 1], [2, 0]], [[2, 1], [3, 0]] # corresponding to 6, 7, 8 entries
[[0, 2], [1, 1]], [[1, 2], [2, 1]], [[2, 2], [3, 1]] # corresponding to 3, 2, 1 entries
```

Basically only taking into account the subarray.

```
6 7 8
3 2 1
```

Also, if it is 3D then there is another axes but with similar rules i.e. only getting the subarray with valid entries. I would then like to use these indexes to manipulate the entries in the original array. However, I am unable to figure out how to efficiently generate these indexes without resorting to loops over the axes (which is also not fixed) of the ndarray.

Comment: How would you define a valid previous neighbour ?

Comment: The valid one is just the index before in the x and y direction as long as it is within the array bounds. So, in my example on the entries 6 7 8 3 2 1 have valid previous indexes because their previous neighbors in the x and y direction exist. The top row has no previous neighbors as they have no valid entries in the y direction and the left most row has no previous neighbors because they have no previous neighbors in the x-direction. I hope I was able to explain that clearly. please let me know if i can provide further clarification.

Comment: Ok so what about 3D ?

Comment: It is the same rules. As long as now there is a valid previous neighbour in x, y and z direction. So, assuming the size of the array is x_, y_, z_ in the three axes, the valid indices will have the form like [1:(x_-1), (1:y_-1), (1:z_1)].

Comment: Sorry, I meant [0:(x_-2), (0:y_-2), (0:z_-2)].

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. In ym case I could simply use numpy indices. So something like:

```
import numpy as np
i = np.indices(x-2 for x in data.shape)
```

Then I can use it as:

```
data[i[0], i[1], i[2]...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider your data given by

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

Then using slicing would give you exactly what you need if I understand you correctly, namely

```
>>> data[1:, 1:]
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [3, 2, 1]])
```

Thus, if valid previous neighbour means that there is a neighbour above and left of these items you just apply the same slicing `1:` to each dimension of your array. In 3D `data[1:, 1:, 1:]` etc.